# htaccess redirect with 301 from a folder that no longer exists

Tags: .htaccess

I've read a number of websites and they all say something different. On my friends site his blog was previously www.bellastairs.com/news now its just the main page so www.bellastairs.com.

What is the easiest way to redirect any hits that no longer exist trying to get to news to redirect to the homepage?

For example [google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=glass%20stairs%20miami&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) searching for glass stairs miami.

He's the second link but its now dead. Is there an easy way to change the htaccess to redirect that permanently to his homepage?

Comment: Yes there is, and the sites say different things because there are many ways to do it. Have you tried any of the solutions you found on those websites?

Comment: No because they also say not to adjust the htaccess if you dont know what you're doing and most of the ones I found didnt explain well. For example a bunch say www.example.com but don't say if that should be the new site or the old site or what.

Comment: So, you're going to get yet another (possibly even more) advices here; how would that make you more confident to edit your `.htaccess` file than when all you had were multiple advices from different other sites? You can always back up your `.htaccess` file and restore it if you mess something up.

Comment: Because lanzz I was hoping that someone would know which set of instructions I should follow for my specific task rather than doing trial and error on a system file

Comment: Follow [the official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html), there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/news /
```